# Show images from drawable - RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to add images from drawable folder to my RecyclerView, but unfortunately nothing is displayed. I dont have any errors and warnings in LogCat. I am trying to add pictures in the flagload void. Below is  Model , part of Adapter and Activity. Layouts for my  application are fine.
Thanks in advance

**MODEL**

```
private int logo;

public JsonMain(int logo) {
    this.logo= logo;
}

public int getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(int logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}
```

**ADAPTER**

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    JsonMain pozycja = filtr.get(position);

    holder.country_flag.setImageResource(pozycja.getLogo());

    holder.country_name.setText(pozycja.getName());
    holder.country_subregion.setText(pozycja.getSubregion());
    holder.country_nativename.setText(pozycja.getNativeName());
    holder.country_capital.setText(pozycja.getCapital());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filtr.size();

}...
```

**ACTIVITY**

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
private List<JsonMain> dataArrayList;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data... Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

}
    private void initViews() {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    loadJSON();

}
    private void loadJSON() {
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://restcountries.eu/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    Call<List<JsonMain>> call = requestInterface.getJSON();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<JsonMain>>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<JsonMain>> call, Response<List<JsonMain>> response) {
            dataArrayList = response.body();
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            flagload();
            dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dataArrayList);


            recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            dataAdapter.setOnitemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.dismiss();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<JsonMain>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error", t.getMessage());
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }


    });}

    private void flagload(){

    JsonMain flag = new JsonMain(R.drawable.asd);
    dataArrayList.add(flag);
    flag = new JsonMain(R.drawable.abc);
    dataArrayList.add(flag);
}...
```

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="4dp" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/country_name"
         android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
         android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/country_subregion"
            android:layout_below="@id/country_name"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/country_nativename"
            android:layout_below="@id/country_subregion"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/country_capital"
            android:layout_below="@id/country_nativename"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: attach your xml.

Comment: You have other parts of CardView updated except ImageView, right? If so, first, check out pozycja.getLogo() is not null and setting imageview with a another drawable to make sure it's working. If getLogo() returns null then check out for JSON data.

Comment: Yest getLogo() returns null but getLogo() use  only data from drawable folder. Other parts of CardView use JSON data